# "You have no more apps available to accept this invitation." when accepting invitation

Tags: google-bigquery

When trying to accept an invitation to an existing project, I see the error message "You have no more apps available to accept this invitation." and am blocked from the project. Googling this phrase returns exactly one page, which does not contain this text. I'm stumped as to how to get added to the project or what this error message is telling me.

Comment: Where you able to solve this? Note that you can share a project on the project's console, or you can share a dataset inside BigQuery. Your message seems to come from the developers console, you shouldn't have this problem if sharing the dataset using BigQuery.

Comment: No, there was no resolution. I ended up inheriting the user account of the creator when he left our team and that's how I got access to the dataset.

Comment: ouch - did you trying sharing at the dataset level instead of project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Create a new dummy project under the invitee's account
2. Delete the project
3. Accept the invitation

Comment: In fact, I did the steps you list in the order 1-3-2 and it worked fine. The important step is to create a dummy project first.

Answer (score 5):

I have also faced same issue,when you have any sample project in invitees cloud console its working fine

Comment: Thanks for the info, but yuck - What an ugly Google bug. ;)

Comment: Ugly, ugly! Just create any project in the console before accepting the invite.